# javaScript function - why my default argument fails?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

My Javascript function leads my console to return me :

> TypeError: style is null

Here the snippet:

```js
let style = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

function styling(style = style, ...ruleSetStock) {

  return ruleSetStock.map(ruleSet => {
    console.log(ruleSet)
    return style[ruleSet]
  })
}

console.log(styling(null, "one", "two", "three"))
```

I can't understand why. It seems to me everything is great,

Any hint would be great,
thanks.

Comment: *"[Default function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) allow named parameters to be initialized with default values if **no value or undefined is passed**"*

Comment: The problem is you are passing null so it will throw an error of null in return line, if its null you want to take the default style object isn't

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Default parameters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) is assigned only if `no value` or `undefined` is passed

```js
let defaultStyle = {  one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }

function styling(style = defaultStyle, ...ruleSetStock) {
  return ruleSetStock.map(ruleSet => {
    return style[ruleSet]
  })
}

console.log(styling(undefined, "one", "two", "three"))
```

> What if i want to use default value on all sorts of `falsy values such as false, '', null`  ?

You can't use default parameter for that but you can use `||`

```js
let style1 = {  one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }

function styling(style, ...ruleSetStock) {
  style = style || style1
  return ruleSetStock.map(ruleSet => {
    return style[ruleSet]
  })
}

console.log(styling(undefined, "one", "two", "three"))
console.log(styling(null, "one", "two", "three"))
console.log(styling('', "one", "two", "three"))
console.log(styling(0, "one", "two", "three"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to update

1. Passing default parameter either no value or undefined
2. changing the style default variable into another name

please see the updated code

```js
let defaultStyle = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

function styling(style = defaultStyle, ...ruleSetStock) {

  return ruleSetStock.map(ruleSet => {
    console.log(ruleSet)
    return style[ruleSet]
  })
}

console.log(styling(undefined, "one", "two", "three"))
```

you can write the above snippet in much more cleaner way using es6

see the below snippet

```
const defaultStyle = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}


const styling = (style = defaultStyle, ...ruleSetStock) => ruleSetStock.map(ruleSet => {
   return style[ruleSet]
})

console.log(styling(undefined, "one", "two", "three"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*cleaner way using es6*"? The OP apparently already was using ES6 with the default initialiser syntax. You might want to point out the specific language feature that you think makes the code cleaner.

Comment: removal of return keywords

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `style` variable into `styles` and then instead of having `null` as your first argument when you invoke `styling`, use `undefined`:

```
const styles = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

function styling(style = styles, ...ruleSetStock) {

  return ruleSetStock.map(ruleSet => {
    console.log(ruleSet)
    return style[ruleSet]
  })
}

console.log(styling(undefined, "one", "two", "three"))
// one
// two
// three
// [1, 2, 3]
```