# How to handle destructuring of function argument with undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

While destructuring function argument, if the function argument is undefined how to handle it?

```
const product = {
    label: 'Notebook',
    price: 50
};

const destructSample = ({label, price}) => {
    console.log(label, price);
}

destructSample(product);
destructSample(undefined);
```

destructSample(undefined); throws following error

```
const destructSample = ({label, price}) => {
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `label` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at destructSample (E:\PlayGround\NodeJs\nodeCourse\playground\destructuringError.js:6:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\PlayGround\NodeJs\nodeCourse\playground\destructuringError.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

How to resolve this?
Thank you.

Comment: The [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578167/es6-object-destructuring-default-parameters) talks about partially defined objects, in the OP's case there's no object at all.

Comment: @georg The duplicate is about *both*.

Comment: @str: yes, the answer happens to be the same, but we're supposed to vote for duplicate questions, not similar answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [`default value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) can be used

```js
const product = {
    label: 'Notebook',
    price: 50
};

const destructSample = ({label, price}= {}) => {
    console.log(label, price);
}

destructSample(product);
destructSample(undefined);
```

***Note:-*** default parameters will come into picture only when there is no arguments passed or undefined is passed as argument, so if you want to handle some more falsy value you can do something like this

```js
const product = {
    label: 'Notebook',
    price: 50
};

const destructSample = (obj) => {
    let {label, price}= obj === undefined || obj === null ? {} : obj
    console.log(label, price);
}

destructSample(product);
destructSample(undefined);
destructSample();
destructSample(null);
```

Related question [`javaScript function - why my default argument fails?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417708/javascript-function-why-my-default-argument-fails/56417734#56417734)